# How do I use keyboard shortcuts on German keyboard?

Tags: google-docs, keyboard-shortcuts

I am trying to use keyboard shortcuts in Google Docs with a German keyboard. In Google Docs keyboard shortcuts are made for American keyboards.

For example: "Increase Indent" needs <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>.

On an American keyboard this is not a problem.

German keyboards don't have the `]` as a key without pressing <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key at the same time. This messes up the shortcut and it doesn't work.
Same for "Search the menus" (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>).

Is there a way to change shortcuts or some workaround?

Here  are my Google language settings:

[image: Google Language Settings]

---

[image: Google Keyboard Settings]

Comment: What's your language set to?

Comment: I use an English (UK) Windows 7, an English Chrome browser and have a German keyboard.

Comment: Do you have the keyboard setting in Region & Language control panel set to your keyboard layout?

Comment: @user3169 : yes keyboard layout is set correctly

Comment: Have you tried to log in from www.google.de? With some luck it might think you are in Germany.

Comment: I do have German as my keyboard layout. Doesn't make a difference. See updated questions, I have added screenshots.

Comment: Same problem here. The only thing that worked for me so far is to switch the Windows keyboard layout to English.
Since you can define a shortcut for that, you can at least switch back and forth easily.

Comment: Seems to be the only option to change keyboad layout. Defeats the purpose a bit. by the time i switched back for forth i can be quicker with the mouse ...

Comment: I have exactly the same problem with a Swedish keyboard. I use Increase Indent all the time in bullet lists.

Answer (score 1):

the trick is to not use actual keys for **`[`** & **`]`** but intended ones:

- **<kbd>Strg</kbd>** + **<kbd>Ü</kbd>**
- **<kbd>Strg</kbd>** + **<kbd>*</kbd>**

[image]

for **`Alt + /`** use:

- **<kbd>Alt</kbd>** + **<kbd>_</kbd>**

[image]

Comment: Hey, do you know how can I get the shortcut in German style?

Answer (score 1):

On a German keyboard you can use <kbd>Tab</kbd> to increase and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>  to decrease indent.

This works for me on a German system with Win 10 and Chrome.